# How to find out the number of Validators of a transaction if i have its transaction hash

Tags: blockchain, mining, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I want to find out how many validators have validated my transaction.My transaction has is 0x051430dc5cd84c44954e43b25f8709c9c1a1c634f384ec6dd7610f6f945732e1

can anyone tell me how many validators validated my transaction in Ethereum blochain.

please help me on this.

Comment: do you mean the number of confirmations?

Comment: You can only have had one `validator` i.e. the miner that added the block i.e wont the proof of work competition

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one validator i.e. the miner that added the block . If you are talking about confirmation, a block is confirmed after the 5th block is added to the chain i.e your block + 5 more blocks. If you take the average blocktime of 15seconds, your block (15s ) + 5 more blocks (5 * 15 = 75) - 90 seconds.

Here is your transaction on aleth.io

https://aleth.io/tx/0x051430dc5cd84c44954e43b25f8709c9c1a1c634f384ec6dd7610f6f945732e1

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [link](https://aleth.io/tx/0x051430dc5cd84c44954e43b25f8709c9c1a1c634f384ec6dd7610f6f945732e1) provided in the previous answer or [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x051430dc5cd84c44954e43b25f8709c9c1a1c634f384ec6dd7610f6f945732e1), you can get to know that your transaction was put into a block numbered `8244682`.

Drilling deeper, this block was created by a miner node who gave her address as `0x5a0b54d5dc17e0aadc383d2db43b0a0d3e029c4c` first. She then broadcasts it to her peers. Technically all the nodes who have received this block from the miner or eventually from any other peer node will run all the transactions in that block and validate it.

So you can say any node that received this particular block has validated your transaction.